# Some restrictions for the class group of cyclic extensions.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, class-field-theory

After searching through the online databases of number fields, I guess the following statements should be true, but I can not prove it.

Let $L/\mathbb{Q}$ be a cyclic Galois extension of prime degree $q$. Let $p\neq q$ be another prime. My Major guess is:

> **Major question**: If $\mathcal{Cl(O}_L) \cong \dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}}$, then $p\stackrel{q}{\equiv} 1$.

If the first statement is true, then I believe its proof would be very clarifying and enlightening for other statements. The second generalized version of the major question is:

> If $\mathcal{Cl(O}_L) \cong (\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{p\mathbb{Z}})^f$, then $p^f\stackrel{q}{\equiv} 1$.

Also, I have some doubts about the third generalized version of that question:

> If $\mathcal{Cl(O}_L) \cong (\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{f'}\mathbb{Z}})^{f''}$, then $p^{f'f''}\stackrel{q}{\equiv} 1$.

---

I strongly doubt the correctness of this last statement, and I think this statement is incorrect.

> Minor question: If $p < q$ and $ \mid \mathcal{Cl(O}_L) \mid = p^f$, then $\mid \mathcal{Cl(O}_L) \mid \stackrel{q}{\equiv} 1$, and $\mathcal{Cl(O}_L) \cong (\dfrac{\mathbb{Z}}{p^{f'}\mathbb{Z}})^{f''}$, with $f'f''=f$.

Comment: See https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0205336 .

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer Thanks for introducing your interesting paper. Clearly, I have not yet had enough time to read it, and I have looked at it casually. I have only read the theorems, and I ignored the proofs. The only thing I have noticed is that $q$ in my question plays the same role as $p$ in your paper. So I will change the role of $p$ and $q$ in my question, to be compatible with the notations of your paper. Also, with the notations in your paper, in my question, $F$ is just $\mathbb{Q}$, and $K$ would be equal to $L$.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer Your paper immediately concludes all three versions (The first three statements) of my Major question. Thank you so much for introducing this beautiful paper.